# Jenkins configuration to DSL code conversion

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl, custom-build-step

I am trying to write the corresponding dsl code for a jenkins job and i am stuck at Build step and don't know how to code **Send Files or Execute commands over SSH**.

I have tried the **XML to DSL converter plugin** but it is also excluding this section.

Can someone help in this?

[Build Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eHMa.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack_overflow. Add the error and what u have tried in question section... You can edit/update the question and help others to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jenkins job DSL method: [publishOverSsh](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.publishOverSsh) to archive your goal.

```
job('test') {

    def cmd = 'mkdir -p $MICROSERVICE_NAME\n' +
              'mv docker-compse.deploy.yml ${MICROSERVICE_NAME}\n' +
              'cd ${MICROSERVICE_NAME}\n'

    steps {
        publishOverSsh {
            server('MiSe_New_External') {
                transferSet {
                    sourceFiles('docker-compse.deploy.yml')
                    execCommand(cmd)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```